# Resizing a button with higher values of Height and Width is less smooth than with lower values in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a button which Max and Min height X width are 1024X1360 and 72X95 pixels. I am resizing this button by handling DragDelta events of Thumbs present in button's Template. The problem is the updation of height and width at lower levels, i.e upto 210X280, gives out a smooth operation which is not the case with greater sizes. Anybody out here has faced the issue? Any suggestion to improve the user experience in this situation.

Comment: Does the button have some complex inner structure, or is it just a solid-color rectangle?

Comment: Not very complex structure...Only few borders and paths are there in the button's Template (and thumbs of course).

Comment: Hi, we've seen it many time, it's got to do with Layout (Measure->Arrange overrides) optimization, you can't sepnd forever trying to resolve it. There's a number of techniques allowing to ease the pain, including Opacity animations and Animation Easying functions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix here is to make the contents of your button less complex.  In general, the more stuff there is to draw inside of it (i.e. larger size) the longer it is going to take to draw it.  This can become even more problematic when you consider that hardware will play an (unpredictable) role in the performance as well.

So a couple of easy options:  Mix and match for best results.
1. Make your button less complex.
2. Limit its maximum size.  (To something smaller)
3. Accept the choppiness.